# Расспарсить Json

Tags: javascript, vue.js

помогите пожалуйста расспарсить json на Vue.js

В итоге хочу получить

8 - Вперед к победе (Турцевич Артём, Карлович Петр)

10 - Рождение звезды (Григорян Эдмон)

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "branch_id": 1,
  "name": "Большой зал",
  "schedule_hall": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "programm_id": 2,
      "time": 8,
      "programm": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Вперед к победе",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 14,
            "child_surname": "Турцевич",
            "child_name": "Артём",
            "programm_id": 2
          },
          {
            "id": 23,
            "child_surname": "Карлович",
            "child_name": "Петр",
            "programm_id": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "programm_id": 3,
      "day": 2,
      "time": 10,
      "programm": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Рождение звезды",
        "branch_id": 1,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 16,
            "child_surname": "Григорян",
            "child_name": "Эдмон",
            "programm_id": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: нет разницы в vue, angular или react вы парсите json. Изучите внимательно структуру вашего json и придумайте алгоритм подходящий для вашей ситуации. В вашем случае все предельно просто

Comment: Для более наглядной структуры json можно использовать: https://jsoneditoronline.org

Answer (score 2):

```
const result = __OBJECT__.schedule_hall.map(i => 
    `${i.time} - ${i.programm.name} (${i.programm.children.map(j => 
            `${j.child_surname} ${j.child_name}`
    ).join(', ')})`
);
```

Вместо `__OBJECT__` Ваш JSON объект